# the back head looks weird

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging

I'm trying to make a model but the head is kinda weird looking like a square on the back.

Am I doing something wrong, or should I just complete the head to see the real result?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are trying to recreate the head from the reference images, yes, you are doing something wrong. While the reference gets narrower downwards to the neck, you have concentrated the vertical edges on one side which makes a sharp edge and also simply builds a more square shape, so it is only natural that it looks square. Also going further up there is something messed up, inbetween all the quads is one n-gon with 5 vertices. I don't know what you did to get it this wrong, but I would redo the back part of the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gordon says the vertical edges are too close to each other, which will create a sharp angle, you'll see it more clearly if you disable the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, or at least disable its *On Cage* option. Instead, move the edges away from each other and you'll have a round shape:

[image]